# Swift 2.1 ErrorType does not conform protocol RawRepresentable

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, rawrepresentable

I have declared error type

```
enum UserServicesError: ErrorType {
    case UserNotLogged
}
```

but I get an error

`Argument type 'UserServicesError' does not conform to expected type 'ErrorType'`

`Type 'UserServicesError' does not conform to protocol 'RawRepresentable'`

Any idea y? Official documentation says that this declaration is sufficient.

[Apple Swift 2.1 Error handling documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH42-ID508)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've finally figure it out. I had declared enum ErrorType in objective-c shared class from pre-swift ages.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ErrorType) {
   ...
};
```

I would expect to see a `Redefined type error` rather than `does not conform to protocol 'RawRepresentable'`

Comment: Yeah - definitely worth filing a radar over. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Are you by any chance using `UserServicesError` with Cocoa classes? If so, the Errors subsection of [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-ID61) suggests it should be declared like this:

```
@objc enum UserServicesError: Int, ErrorType {
    case UserNotLogged
}
```

The `@objc` designation is needed for any protocols that interact with Objective-C Cocoa objects. Conforming to `Int` (or some other `RawRepresentable`-conforming type) gets you `RawRepresentable` conformance automatically (vs. leaving it a pure Swift `enum`).

I hope this helps. If it does, let me know if it was one, the other, or both needed to fix it. I'm curious. :-)

Comment: Unfortunately no, the class is pure swift and is not called anywhere else than from that class.